# Have to click submit twice for AJAX request to fire on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

My Form HTML looks like this.

```
<form novalidate action="register.php" method="post" >
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Your username" autofocus/>

    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" cid="submit" />
</form>
```

And My jQuery looks like this

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();    
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { formData: serializedData },
        datetype: "JSON"
    });
    request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("HELLO");
        $('form').unbind(); 
        $('form').submit();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The sad thing is that it logs `hello` to the console but it never submits the form with one click on the submit button. I need to press two times to submit button.

Can anyone tell me the problem and how can I fix it so that 1 click is sufficient for form submission.

NOTE: The data of form is send for validation not actually for submission . If data like email  , username etc are valid i want the form to be submitted with one click.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in jquery code after ajax request done $("form").submit(); is suppose to submit form, isn't it??

Comment: @Blazemonger As per your suggestion i edited the code still i need to press submit button two times ?

Comment: How about binding on the click event of the input (make it a `<button type='button'></button>` and then call submit. This way you don't have to prevent the default action on the form nor deal with binding/unbinding the submit action?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a side effect of the ajax call taking a second or two to respond?

Comment: @NOthingYouknowme, did you actually solve your problem? I have the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think it would be cleaner to use a success function instead of a .done() function. For example:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    request = $.ajax({
        // Merge the check.php and register.php into one file so you don't have to  'send' the data twice.
        url: "register.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { formData: serializedData },
        datetype: "JSON",
        success: function() {
            console.log("This form has been submitted via AJAX");
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that I removed the .unbind() function, as I suspect it might be the reason your code is acting up. It removes the event handlers from the form, regardless of their type (see: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). Also, I put the e.preventDefault() at the start. I suggest you try this edited piece of code, and let us know if it does or does not work.

EDIT: Oh, and yeah, you don't need to submit it when you're sending the data via AJAX.

Comment: Do form submits?? i only see e.preventDefaults(); but i cannot see any .submit() ??

Comment: i uses ajax for validation .. so if php returns true thorugh help of ajax i want to submit form actally .

Comment: I just edited my answer accordingly. As you're using two different php files, I'm convinced you can merge the two and integrate the 'check' into the 'register' file. If you send the data via AJAX to the register.php file, validate it using the check function you copied from the check.php file, and use it in the register function. That way you don't have to 'submit' the form in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the validation from the form submit.

Simply changing this line:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
```

to

```
$("input[name='register']").click(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();    
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { formData: serializedData },
        datetype: "JSON"
    });
    request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("HELLO");
        $('form').unbind(); 
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { formData: serializedData },
        datatype: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

So, to break it down.

Stop the form submission with the preventDefault().

Get the form data and submit it to your validator script.

The return value, I assume, is a boolean value. If it validated, it'll be true, or false.

Return the value which will continue the form submission or end it.

NB.: This is a horrible way to validate your forms. I'd be validating my forms on the server with the form submission, because javascript can be terribly easily monkeyed with. Everything from forcing a true response from the server to turning the submission event listener off.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have the same issue 
What I found is I have some bug in my url xxx.php
it may return error message like "Notice: Undefined variable: j in xxx.php on line ....."
It may let ajax run unexpected way.
Just for your info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing prevent default when clicking a submit button, you can create a normal button and fire a function when you click it, at the end of that function, submit the form using `$('#form').submit();`. No more confusing prevent default anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call `submit()` since you are posting your data via ajax.

**EDIT** You may need to adjust the `contentType` and/or other ajax params based on your needs. PHP example is very basic. Your form is most likely much more complex. Also, you will want to sanitize any php data - don't rely on just the `$_POST`

**jQuery:**

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'url': 'post.php',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': { formData: $(this).serialize},
        'timeout': 50000
     ).done(function(data) {
         // Response from your validation script
         if (data === true)
         {
            // SUCCESS!
         }
         else
         {
             // Something happened.
         }
     ).fail(function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**PHP**

```
$is_valid = FALSE;
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($name !== '')
{
     $is_valid = TRUE;
}
else
{
   return FALSE;
}

if ($is_valid)
{
    // insert into db or email or whatver
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I am actually using it for validation . If ajax returned true value i want the form to submit . but if not i want to give the user to see the response got from ajax.

Comment: I see. You (could) just do validation & submit in the same php file. Or, I have edited above to send to another file.

Comment: Yes when i do $(this).submit() i need to press two times.. that is the main problem.. it has irritated me so much :( .

Comment: Can you combine your validation & submit php files? I have an example above.

Comment: yes when if (data === true){} i want the form to get submited ..  i added $(this).submit() but need to press two times :( why is such things happening?